# How to add a theme button, when clicked will change html background and buttons colour of that page

Tags: html, button, colors, background, themes

How to add a theme button, when clicked will change html background and buttons colour of that page. I have made some searches here but lots of Background colour change answers are there. I request some one to tell me how to change the button color also, with another button click.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you can create this function that takes two target colors and compares with actual colors, changing the body background, then the button background if the body had changed already.

[working solution here](https://codepen.io/aledebarba/pen/VwPWZGv)

or run the snippet below

```js
function changeColor ( bodyTargetColor, buttonTargetColor ) {
       var firstClick = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor != bodyTargetColor ? true : false;
       if (firstClick) { 
          document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor = bodyTargetColor;
          return false;
      } 
      document.getElementById('changeColors').style.backgroundColor = buttonTargetColor;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 98%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#changeColors {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<button 
        id="changeColors"
        onclick="changeColor('darkslategray','olive')"
        >Change Colors</buton>
```

Comment: I mean to say there are 4 buttons in my HTML page. 5th button need for theme color change. one button click should change all other button colors. I'll give my code for buttons and bg below
<body style="background-color:Aliceblue;">
<style>
        .link_button {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #20538D;
    background: DodgerBlue;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
    </style>

Comment: Anybody with any response for the above question.

Comment: There is some approaches to do that. You could use custom properties (css variables) at :root level with your theme colors. Then setup your styles to use the custom properties and change the custom properties values with javascript, like 
`<body style="background-color: var(--theme-background)"> <button style="background-color: var(--btn-custom-color);" onclick="changeTheme()"></button>`. You can see a working example here: [workin example at codepen](https://codepen.io/aledebarba/pen/oNBVPpr)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, TYSM @ Alexandre Macedo. I'll develop this code according to my requirement.